# I need to realize FIFO algorithm

Tags: r, dataframe, fifo

I have a data frame like:

```
items = data.frame(
  Items = c('Item A', 'Item B','Item A','Item A','Item A','Item B','Item B','Item A','Item C'),
  Quantity = c(5,100,4,7,10,50,30,1,1000),
  BuySell = c('B','B','B','S','B','S','S','S','B'),
  Price = c(100,50,110,130,90,45,60,120,5)
)

items$Value = items$Quantity * items$Price
```

I need to group items by name and calculate the amount and value of balances using the FIFO method. When we sell an item, we sell first by date (table grouped by date of operation). And we need to calculate the value of items which weren't sold.

I need to get the result of movement items (buy & sell) with their value by FIFO (first in, first out)

In my example results have to be:

> ```
> Item A:
> ```

```
 Quantity: 11 Value 1000 
Item B:
 Quantity: 20 Value 1000
Item C:
 Quantity: 1000 Value 5000
```

Comment: How do you get those quantities/values? For example where did `Value 130` come from? Similarly with `Item B`... Why `Quantity 20`?

Comment: Because Buy: (quantity) 100, Sell 50 + 30

Comment: I don't see any dates in that example.

Comment: It is really hard to follow your logic. You should explain the steps of @Sotos question clearly by editing your question.

Comment: We buy and sell goods (Items A, B, C). Purchases and sales take place at different prices. When there is a sale of a previously purchased product, this product is deducted from the warehouse. And the rest of the goods is estimated at the purchase price of the goods that remained. The sale is debited first from the first batch of purchased goods of the same name, then the second and so on.

Comment: I can follow the logic in B and C but I suspect sth is wrong with item A?

Comment: Oh... sorry. You are right. It have to be in result by Item A: Quantity: 11 Value: 1 * 100 + 10 * 90 = 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

items <- items %>% 
  group_by(Items) %>% 
  mutate(index = 1:n()) %>% 
  spread(BuySell, Quantity, fill = 0) %>% 
  arrange(Items, index) %>% 
  mutate(TotalStock = cumsum(B) - cumsum(S), 
         Sold = case_when(B == 0 ~ 0, # Nothing bought - cannot be sold
                          cumsum(B) < sum(S) ~ B, # Total items bought is smaller than total item sold - everything is sold
                          sum(S) < (cumsum(B) - B) ~ 0, # Total sum is smaller than total amount bought excluding the current buy - nothing sold
                          TRUE ~ B - (cumsum(B) - sum(S))), 
         InStock = B - Sold)
```

This gives the following `data.frame`

```
items
# A tibble: 9 x 9
# Groups:   Items [3]
#   Items  Price Value index     B     S TotalStock  Sold InStock
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Item A   100   500     1     5     0          5     5       0
# 2 Item A   110   440     2     4     0          9     3       1
# 3 Item A   130   910     3     0     7          2     0       0
# 4 Item A    90   900     4    10     0         12     0      10
# 5 Item A   120   120     5     0     1         11     0       0
# 6 Item B    50  5000     1   100     0        100    80      20
# 7 Item B    45  2250     2     0    50         50     0       0
# 8 Item B    60  1800     3     0    30         20     0       0
# 9 Item C     5  5000     1  1000     0       1000     0    1000
```

and this can be summarized as

```
items %>% 
  summarize(Value = sum(InStock * Price), 
            TotalStock = sum(InStock))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Items  Value TotalStock
#   <fct>  <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Item A  1010         11
# 2 Item B  1000         20
# 3 Item C  5000       1000
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work when TotalStock is negative in the beginning?

I'm dealing with a case where initial Stock for Item A can be negative (short selling in trading, for example)

Brilliant code, however =)

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the quantity column to contain positive/negative for buy/sell:

```
items$Quantity <- items$Quantity * ifelse(items$BuySell=="B",1,-1)
```

Next, explore how to perform logic using a subset of the data, say for Item B:

```
x <- items[items$Items == "Item B",]
unsold <- sum(x$Quantity)
x <- x[seq(nrow(x),1,-1),]  # reverse order (unsold items are at bottom)
x <- x[x$Quantity > 0,]     # consider buy only
x$cs <- cumsum(x$Quantity)  # cumulative bought amount
x$cs <- pmin(x$cs, unsold)
if(nrow(x) > 1) x[-1,"cs"] <- diff(x$cs) # cs column now holds the amount relevant for cost calculation
```

This will give you:

```
 list("Quantity" = unsold, "Value" = sum(x$cs * x$Price))
#$Quantity
#[1] 20
#
#$Value
#[1] 1000
```

Next we wrap then into a function, so that we can call it by a subset of the data frame:

```
calculate.lv <- function(x){

    unsold <- sum(x$Quantity)
    x <- x[seq(nrow(x),1,-1),]  # reverse order (unsold items are at bottom)
    x <- x[x$Quantity > 0,]     # consider buy only
    x$cs <- cumsum(x$Quantity)  # cummulative bought amount
    x$cs <- pmin(x$cs, unsold)
    if(nrow(x) > 1) x[-1,"cs"] <- diff(x$cs)    # cs column now holds the amount relevant for cost calculation
    
    list("Quantity" = unsold, "Value" = sum(x$cs * x$Price))
}

calculate.lv(items[items$Items=="Item C",])
#$Quantity
#[1] 1000
#
#$Value
#[1] 5000
```

Finally, we use the `by` function to apply the function onto slices of the data frame:

```
by(items, list(items$Items), calculate.lv)
#: Item A
#$Quantity
#[1] 11
#
#$Value
#[1] 1010
#
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#: Item B
#$Quantity
#[1] 20
#
#$Value
#[1] 1000
#
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#: Item C
#$Quantity
#[1] 1000
#
#$Value
#[1] 5000
#
```